# Changing the style of ASP.NET Dropdown box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, css

I have a default ASP.NET Dropdown, and it is rendered with a select tag id of "Countries".

I'd like the background of the drop-down to be transparent to match with the background of the page, and also like to keep make the default border disappear as well, so it blends well with the background. The list items can have the white background. I have an image of a custom arrow that i'd like to use instead of the default one that is used to click on the drop-down.

On hovering over the drop-down list items, I'd like the background of the item to be yellow, and the font color should always be black.

I'd like to use CSS 2.1 as much as possible for this, but if it's too complex then I'm willing to use javscript or jquery.

Below is the rendered markup, and some custom styles I've been trying to write. I also think some of the styles are overwritten by some default ones. Any help to finish this styling would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

```
<select name="ContriesDropdown" class="Select.SmallSelect" id="Countries" style="width: 100px; background-color: white;" onblur="try{FormUtils_ElementErrorReset(this);}catch(e){}" onchange="Send(this.value);">

<option value="1">Country1

<option value="2">Country2

*CustomCss*

#Countries {   position:absolute; display:inline; top:6px;}

#Countries {background-color:transparent; vertical-align: middle; color: #44586D; border: 0px transparent; display: inline;padding:2px;}

#Countries Option:hover { color:black; background-color:Yellow; }
```

Comment: I think that you'll find that the <select> element (like the checkbox and radio elements) have very limited styling options.

Comment: Yeah, but to maintain consistency of the page I must style this. Could you please help ?

Comment: you can use jquery to apply style on dropdownbox , check jquery selectbox if i remember right i used that to change dropdown into div and style it at runtime which doesnt affect asp.net control working at all

Answer (score 1):

Try This.

```
select
    {
        -webkit-appearance: button;
        -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        -webkit-padding-end: 20px;
        -webkit-padding-start: 2px;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        background-image: url(../images/select-arrow.png), -webkit-linear-    gradient(#FAFAFA, #F4F4F4 40%, #E5E5E5);
        background-position: center right;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        border: 1px solid #AAA;
        color: #555;
        font-size: 10pt;
        margin: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding-top: 2px;
        padding-bottom: 2px;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        white-space: nowrap;
        font-family: Cambria;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The default ASP.Net controls are very limited when it comes to styling. You should try using external controls like the JQuery UI dropdown instead.

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox

Comment: That would work because it replaces the <select> with other controls.

Comment: I am not allowed to use anything other than the asp.net controls. That's the issue. I can use custom javascript or jquery if needed. Thanks

Comment: Exactly its actually a combination of different controls which offer a very flexible control in terms of styling

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think what you want is possible with a normal ASP.Net dropdown, which actually is just a normal <select> control.

Comment: You can use that JQuery widget on top of an ASP Dropdown list, I'm not seeing the problem here.